# biblatex: Something like \ifentrytype

Tags: biblatex, conditionals

I’d like to change the bibmacro `cite:short` only for one entry type (`@music`). So is there a way to test for the entry type?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `\iffieldequalstr` command to check for a specific entry type.

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:short}{%     
    \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{music}
      {} %true
      {} %false
}
```

From the biblatex [manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) (p. 147)

> `\iffieldequalstr{<field>}{<string>}{<true>}{<false>}`
>
> Executes `<true>` if the value of the
>   `<field>` is equal to `<string>`, and
>   `<false>` otherwise. This command is
>   robust.

Comment: You are my hero ;-) I didn’t know that I can access `entrytype` in this way. Maybe I should read the whole manual in nearer future …

Answer (score 21):

Actually, `biblatex` *does* feature an `\ifentrytype` macro, but it was undocumented until version 1.7. Quoting section 4.6.2 of the manual:

> `\ifentrytype{<type>}{<true>}{<false>}`
>
> Executes `<true>` if the entry type of the entry currently being
>   processed is `<type>`, and `<false>` otherwise.

And quoting appendix D (Revision History):

> 1.7 2011-11-13
>
> [...]
>
> Added missing documentation for `\ifentrytype`

Comment: Thank you! I’ll keep Thorsten’s answers as accepted because he has less reputation, although yours is the better on according to the question title. I hope you don’t mind :-)

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. Accepting an answer is not a means for giving away rep, but for marking the most helpful answer so people who find this question later will immediately recognize it.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Well, at the time of asking, the answer of Thorsten probably was the most helpful so it should stay to be the accepted answer.  (I wasn't even aware of the fact that one possibly *could* change the accepted answer more than  10 months later, but apparently that is actually possible.)

Comment: @Daniel This doesn't make sense. When someone asks a question, s/he is referred to an identical question which has already been answered (if such exists). From this it immediately follows that answers should reflect the **current** optimal state of affairs (even adapting answers to new developments) and not some historical considerations at the time of asking.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Yeah, it doen't make a lot of sense. It is more related to the community process: We have to separate two things here: (1) The answer that has helped the OP "most" and (2) the "best / most complete" answer. For (1), the criteria is just in the eye of the OP – the accepted answer might be suboptimal or even wrong, but we have to live with the fact that many OPs never come back to change it. So (2) is in the responsibility of the community, who has to indicate the "best" answer by upvoting (and maybe even downvoting a really bad "accepted" answer).

Comment: Daniel Oh well this is very nice from an abstract point of view, but in this particular case I was answering to a comment by the **very** OP stating he didn't want to accept the best answer to avoid throwing rep on the larger heap. If it's all about the rep, he could do as @Paulo did and give a bounty to Thorsten. But you would do a much better service to the community by encouraging this actual OP who's still reading and writing here to accept the better answer.

Comment: To conclude this discussion, I posted a question on [meta] (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2387/12850).